# Is it possible to block the government from seeing my IMEI?

Tags: imei

Is it possible to mask my IMEI on my device? I know the government is used to track the phones via IMEI. I am interested in just blocking carriers/providers to view my IMEI when I am having an issue with the phones or an employee views my account. Is this possible?

Comment: The government asks the provider for access. They don't have their own access.

Comment: If you are asking about blocking the cell provider's access to the IMEI, then you need to read about what an IMEI is ...

Comment: Removing or spoofing your IMEI would be the equivalent of Removing or spoofing your IP address in TCP/IP ... it would fundamentally break how the network relays information back to you.  Its not realistic.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to mask my IMEI on my device?

It may be possible to reprogram the IMEI, but this is forbidden by law in some regions.

Furthermore, if you did manage to reprogram the IMEI then you will most likely not be able to use the reprogrammed phone as a phone--the cell service provider likely won't allow the phone to connect to their cell network. This is because the cell service provider uses the IMEI to identify the physical equipment (similar to how the IMSI is used to identify the subscriber) and they likely won't allow a rogue device to connect to their cell network.